# Excel Fill Single Values in a Different Column using IF AND functions?

Tags: excel, if-statement, copy, boolean-logic, fill

I have a table that somewhat looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to spread the values on column B using an IF-AND function so that it would pull the values from column A until it reaches a new value in the column.

I have tried `=IF(AND(A2="",A3="",A1<>""),A1,A2)` for cell A2, but while the function recognizes the beginning of a new value, it ends up in 0s all in between.

[image]

How should I adjust the function to be able to fill the cells with corresponding values? I appreciate the help.

Comment: =IF(A2="",B1,A2)

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to enter a value in B1 by hand, starting in B2 you can use:

```
=IF(A2="",B1,A2)
```

If not, and if you don't mind using a volatile* formula, starting in B1 you can use:

```
=IF(A1="",OFFSET(A1,-1,1),A1)
```

*Note: a volatile formula is one which causes an entire workbook to recalculate whenever **any** change is made. This can significantly slow down a workbook.

Answer (score 0):

The adjusted formula is =IF(A2="",B1,A2). It basically pulls the value from above if the cell to the left is empty, and if it isn't empty, it pulls the value from the cell to the left.

[The corrected formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcQ3q.png)